# Numbered Symbology ARCgis PRO "Text string" by expression

Tags: expression, arcgis

I'm trying to make a numbered Symbology (NOT LABEL) on a feature.
It's possible to use an expression in "Text String" option?
Like: "Parcel no: " + $feature.OBJECTID

[config pannel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sweTW.png)

I have tried several syntax and languages and I get message "The expression is uncommitted".
Can I get any help?
Thanks,
Júlio Almeida

Comment: i have found the solution in the esri community
[link](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/using-attribute-as-symbology-in-arcgis-pro/m-p/1103215#M46157)